# Give the result analytically $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^{2m} \theta \ln{\sin\theta} \cos{2n\theta} d\theta$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Question as title showed, where m and n are positive integers. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set
$$ I(m,n)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2m}\theta \cos(2n\theta)\,d\theta $$
then our integral is just $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial m}I(m,n)$. By using Fourier series, contour integration or the Euler Beta function it is not difficult to check that:
$$ I(m,n) = \frac{\pi\,(-1)^n}{4^m}\binom{2m}{m+n} $$
hence it follows that, provided that $m\geq n$:
$$ J(m,n)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2m}\theta \cos(2n\theta)\log(\sin\theta)\,d\theta=I(m,n)\left(H_{2m}-\frac{H_{m-n}+H_{m+n}}{2}-\log 2\right).$$

Comment: While how to get the last equation?

Comment: And what H stands for?

Comment: @Peng: $$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$$ is the $n$-th harmonic number.

Comment: @Peng: the last equation is derived from $f'(z)=f(z)\cdot\frac{d}{dz}\log f(z)$ and from $\frac{d}{dz}\log\Gamma(z)=\psi(z)=H_{z-1}-\gamma$.

Comment: Much appreciated.